# send email function

Tags: php, email-templates, send-mail

I know it doesn't work but how can i fit $salesData and $salesData2 into the send email function?

```
$salesData['email']  = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom3/email');
$salesData['name']   = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom3/name');
$salesData2['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom4/email');
$salesData2['name']  = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom4/name');
```

Is there a way to do something like so?

```
$emailTemplate->send($salesData && $salesData2, $product->getStoreId(), $emailTemplateVariables);
```

Seems so simple but my brain isn't working today. The above does not work.

Should I use `addTo` or `$email->addBcc()`